# "Developer Inactive" on Beats Music server-side auth token request

Tags: beatsmusic

I'm working on a project and a new Beats Music API library for Clojure, but in my testing I'm finding it difficult to get write access authentication, but read-only user authentication works fine.

In testing my library I set up a HTML page to do the OAuth and get the OAuth code and then feed that code in to my library to fetch the actual authentication token. The first part works flawlessly, the second part has the dreaded "Developer Inactive" error:

```
URL: /oauth/token
PARAMS: client_secret, client_id, redirect_uri, code, grant_type=authorization_code
METHOD: post (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)
```

I've double checked my redirect_uri is the same as defined in my app settings and is the url of the HTML page I generated the code with. I even checked with the support folks to double check that my application wasn't throttled or something, but that took too long and I made a second application and had the exact same results. I've looked at other support questions like this and nothing has helped, so unless I'm missing something in my auth request, my only other thought was that my user account is still on it's 14-day trail and maybe that is affecting my auth token in some way?

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the URL really `/oauth/token`? The correct endpoint is `/oauth2/token`

Comment: Wow, yup. I've clearly been staring at this for too long (and their error codes suck). That was indeed a problem. My app was also apparently throttled and support helped me with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jsd pointed out in [a comment on my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028518/developer-inactive-on-beats-music-server-side-auth-token-request#comment37083424_24028518), there was a typo in the url endpoint. The correct endpoint is (which I had in the other function and that's why it was working correctly):

```
/oauth2/token
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.beatsmusic.com/docs/read/getting_started/Client_Side_Applications
"The scope of an access token using the implicit flow is limited to read only since client side applications cannot keep a secret. You'll need to request the authorization grant flow via the Web Server Authentication for write permissions, such as updating a playlist."

I hope this helps.

Comment: No, I'm aware of the differing scope for client side vs server side. As I detail above, the read-only / client side auth works fine. The problem I'm having is with the server side / web server auth. That's the query I have detailed out (note the grant_time=authorization_code)